# join query with numerical comparison in hive

Tags: hive

i am having issues with the below  hive query at TEMP.total_labor_hours >= (.95 * M.MAX_HOURS), Please suggest how i can rewrite it

```
 `SELECT BAC,COUNTRY_CD,COUNT(*)
FROM DL_EDGE_LRF_GWM_13929_BASE_GWMCNPD_COGNOSDBO.RISK_IND_CALC_TEMP AS TEMP
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT LABOR_OPERATION_KEY,LABOR_OPERATION_CD,LABOR_OPERATION_CD_EN,MAKE,MODEL,MAX_HOURS
  FROM DL_EDGE_LRF_GWM_13929_BASE_GWMCNPD_COGNOSDBO.RISK_IND_03_TMP1) M
ON M.LABOR_OPERATION_KEY = TEMP.LABOR_OPERATION_KEY
AND TEMP.UMF_XREF_FINC_MKTG_DIV = M.MAKE
AND TEMP.UMF_XREF_FINC_BRAND = M.MODEL
AND TEMP.total_labor_hours >= (.95 * M.MAX_HOURS)
WHERE TEMP.transaction_type_key IN ('16','17') AND TEMP.PROCESS_STATUS_key = '11'
GROUP BY BAC,COUNTRY_CD`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have non equi joins in hive.

Rewrite the query using where clause-

```
 `SELECT BAC,COUNTRY_CD,COUNT(*)
FROM DL_EDGE_LRF_GWM_13929_BASE_GWMCNPD_COGNOSDBO.RISK_IND_CALC_TEMP AS TEMP , DL_EDGE_LRF_GWM_13929_BASE_GWMCNPD_COGNOSDBO.RISK_IND_03_TMP1 M
where M.LABOR_OPERATION_KEY = TEMP.LABOR_OPERATION_KEY
AND TEMP.UMF_XREF_FINC_MKTG_DIV = M.MAKE
AND TEMP.UMF_XREF_FINC_BRAND = M.MODEL
AND TEMP.total_labor_hours >= (.95 * M.MAX_HOURS) AND TEMP.transaction_type_key IN ('16','17') AND TEMP.PROCESS_STATUS_key = '11'
GROUP BY BAC,COUNTRY_CD`;
```

Above query would result in cross join and then filters the data based on where conditions.
If its taking more time then change the join condition, Below would be the query -

```
 `SELECT BAC,COUNTRY_CD,COUNT(*)
FROM DL_EDGE_LRF_GWM_13929_BASE_GWMCNPD_COGNOSDBO.RISK_IND_CALC_TEMP AS TEMP
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT LABOR_OPERATION_KEY,LABOR_OPERATION_CD,LABOR_OPERATION_CD_EN,MAKE,MODEL,MAX_HOURS
  FROM DL_EDGE_LRF_GWM_13929_BASE_GWMCNPD_COGNOSDBO.RISK_IND_03_TMP1) M
ON M.LABOR_OPERATION_KEY = TEMP.LABOR_OPERATION_KEY
AND TEMP.UMF_XREF_FINC_MKTG_DIV = M.MAKE
AND TEMP.UMF_XREF_FINC_BRAND = M.MODEL
where M.MAX_HOURS IS NOT NULL AND TEMP.total_labor_hours >= (.95 * M.MAX_HOURS)
TEMP.transaction_type_key IN ('16','17') AND TEMP.PROCESS_STATUS_key = '11'
GROUP BY BAC,COUNTRY_CD`
```

Comment: when i execute the suggested query i am getting an error  "cannot recognize input near  '.95' '*' in input specification"